# React Native - Change other icons color on click

Tags: react-native

I've been searching for a few days to solve this problem. I need to change another icon's color when i click in one of them.

I'm using react-native-vector-icons

```
 this.setState({
        listaPlantel: Object.entries(dataArray).map(function ([key, nome]) {
            if (that.state.mercado.status_mercado == 2) {
                dadosAtleta = that.state.pontuados[nome.atleta_id];
            }
            return (
                <ListItem avatar key={key} button onPress={() => that.detailsScreen(nome)}>
                    <Left>
                        <Thumbnail source={{ uri: nome.foto.replace('FORMATO', '80x80') }} />
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Text>{nome.apelido}</Text>
                        <Text note>{that.state.posicoes ? that.state.posicoes[nome.posicao_id]['nome'] : ''} - {that.state.clubes ? that.state.clubes[nome.clube_id]['nome'] : ''}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Última: {nome.pontos_num} Média: {nome.media_num} {' $' + nome.preco_num}</Text>
                    </Body>
                    <Right>
                        {/*<Text>{dadosAtleta ? dadosAtleta['pontuacao'] : nome.pontos_num}</Text>*/}
                        <Icon name="md-close-circle" size={30} />
                        <Icon type="Foundation" name="md-contact" key={key} size={30} color={that.state.id_capitao === nome.atleta_id ? that.state.corCap : that.state.corGeral} onPress={() => that.setState({ id_capitao: nome.atleta_id })} />
                    </Right>
                </ListItem>
            )
        }),
    });
```

Comment: Could you include all your code? You should only include state changes within setState for example `this.setState({key : "value"});` Please include the `render()` method

Comment: gist.github.com/lnascimento01/29e6c856f340359885a84cc37177a1c4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are putting conditions and functions within `setState` I would recommend you read about the lifecycle and app state here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

As an example of how to update values, of which you're trying to do - take this scenario into consideration:

> initial colour : red, updated colour : blue (For example)

in your constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        /*Initial State and Colour*/
      iconColour : "red"
    }
}
```

in your render method:

```
 <ListItem avatar key={key} button onPress={() => that.detailsScreen(nome)}>
    <Icon color={this.state.iconColour}/>
 </ListItem>
```

Within your onPress function:

```
this.setState({
  iconColor : "blue"
})
```